# Slashdotted web site seeks new home

Tags: web-hosting, scalability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am maintaining a website that contains mostly simple html (just a little php).

Normally the site receives only 4000 hits per month, but it was recently slashdotted by the New York Times (>30,000 visitors and 30 GB in a day) and the web host provider (bluehost) throttled the CPU in response.

This slowed down the website considerably. What web host providers would offer a more scalable solution?

Ideally I would like a high-quality host that charges by the GB and can handle bandwidth to expand during sudden slashdotting episodes without a reduction in performance.

Comment: These days the "slashdot effect" tends to be the "twitter effect" :)

Comment: I'm now giving nearlyfreespeech.net a try. It seems simpler than setting up AWS and cheaper than Rackspace, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider [moving your site to the cloud](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/can-you-store-your-site-entirely-with-amazon-web-services) so that you can almost have unlimited scalability but still [pay for what you use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376273/average-amazon-ec2-instance-price-for-web-hosting/476523#476523).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard very good things of [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com), you might one to check one of its options.